# NiFI data transfer rate

Tags: hadoop, jvm, apache-nifi

I have a stand-alone installation of NIFI-1.4.0 and doing a data transfer between 2 Hadoop clusters. (Exploring as a back up option for DistCP when the clusters running full capacity).

I see the max. transfer rate is around 500MB/Sec and i have tuned parallelism as max as possible and also the buffer size but transfer rate is not going beyond 150 meg/sec. Our network  is 10 Gig so, something is getting limited from NIFI side.

Please advise on where to look.

JVM size i tried with default(512 MB), 4 GB and 8 GB but not effect.

Comment: Have you measured the transfer rate between your server and each HDFS cluster outside of NiFi? It would be good to test a transfer to each cluster using Hadoop client outside of NiFi to make sure it is not a general network issue. Also, information about the disk(s) of the NiFi machine and how the repositories are configured would be helpful.

Comment: checked network speed and it's good. suspecting TCP socket connection MTU is limiting my transfer rate. But  not sure how to prove that